# pandas: calculate percentage change of timeseries from a specific date based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am struggling with the most efficient way to accomplish the following.  I have a timeseries dataframe.
Based on some condition, i set a Boolean column.  After that i would like to generate another column that is the percentage from the last occurrence of the condition.  So for example in the below table,
Row's 2,4, and 5 are the percentage of the value from row 1.  and rows 6,7 and 7 are the percentage change from row 5.

```
row date        value  condition    pct_change_from_condition
1   04-27-2010  100    TRUE             
2   04-28-2010  200                 1.0
4   04-29-2010  300                 2.0
5   04-30-2010  400    TRUE         3.0
6   05-01-2010  500                 0.25
7   05-02-2010  600                 0.5
8   05-03-2010  700                 0.75
```

I know i can iterate over the rows and do this..but since this is pandas, i would like a more 'pandemic' and efficient way of doing this...im just not sure how that might be done here.
It feels like i need something like a conditional shift:

```
df['pct_change_from_condition'] = (df.value - df.shift(df.condition).value)/df.value
```

or maybe using loc:

```
df['pct_change_from_condition'] = df.value - df.loc[df.condition].value
```

Ofcourse these do not work, hence why i am here asking...
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can compare the `condition` column with `TRUE` to create a boolean mask then `mask` the values in the column `value` corresponding to this boolean mask followed by `shift` and `ffill` to create a series `s`, now subtract and divide `value` from/by `s` to calculate percent change

```
m = df['condition'].eq('TRUE')
s = df['value'].mask(~m).shift().ffill()
df['% change'] = df['value'].sub(s).div(s)
```

---

```
         date  value condition  % change
1  04-27-2010    100      TRUE       NaN
2  04-28-2010    200       NaN      1.00
4  04-29-2010    300       NaN      2.00
5  04-30-2010    400      TRUE      3.00
6  05-01-2010    500       NaN      0.25
7  05-02-2010    600       NaN      0.50
8  05-03-2010    700       NaN      0.75
```

Comment: Elegant solution +1, if you use: `df['condition'].isna()` and insert it in the `.mask` you have only 2 lines and similar readbility.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas good suggestion but IMHO this would only work if there are not other values in the column `value` apart from `TRUE`. For example in case  there is a `FALSE` value too then we would have to explicitly check for `TRUE` values to create a mask

Comment: @Andreas Your solution is also good +1 ;)

Comment: Two follow up on this, for my knowledge: 
1.  What is the purpose of the mask here? I was not familiar with that function prior to this.  It reads like it my be similar to what i was asking - a 'shift' based on a condition.
2.  if the condition column is boolean, i assume this will work also: 
 df['value'].mask(df.condition).shift().ffill()

Comment: [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) function is used  here to replace values with `NaN` where the condition is `True`. Here we are masking the values with `NaN` because in the next step we need to forward fill the values in the column `value` with last running `value` where the condition holds `True`. If the `condition` column is already boolean type then you can certainly use `df['value'].mask(~df.condition).shift().ffill()`

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mask = (df['condition'] == True)
df['group'] = mask.cumsum()
df['first'] = df.groupby(['group'])['value'].transform('first')
df['first'] = np.where(mask, df['first'].shift(), df['first'])
df['pct_change'] = (df['value']-df['first'])/df['first']

# Out[52]: 
# 0     NaN
# 1    1.00
# 2    2.00
# 3    3.00
# 4    0.25
# 5    0.50
# 6    0.75
# Name: pct_change, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is by keeping a running sum of `condition == True` (shifted by 1), using `.groupby()` using that running sum, and for each group, calculate the percentages w.r.t the appropriate reference.